# does Admin-on-rest provides date-range-picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, admin-on-rest

I want to have a filter where I can filter from date to a particular date ie date range picker. does Admin on rest provides anything like that?  any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options for the front-end/react-admin part of your problem:

- [Official react-admin's DateField](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#datefield)
- [React-Admin date inputs npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-admin-date-inputs)
- [Material-UI's date pickers](https://material-ui.com/demos/pickers/)

Once you've chosen which of these options is optimal for your case, you have to manipulate your data on the back-end. 
I.e. you can create a filter in which you'll use two date pickers to define your start and end date, then pass this data to your back-end, where, with the use of filtering you can return data according to these dates.

Also please study react-admin's [documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#filters) on custom filtering and be careful not to mix up *Filter* with *filters*.